# How i can printf result like 0.0045

Tags: iphone, audio

```
     I only get this
```

1667785316

1667785316

1667785316

```
     Float32 preferredBufferSize = 0.005; // 5 millis buffer
  UInt32 size = sizeof(preferredBufferSize);


    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration, &size,
                &preferredBufferSize);
   printf("\n%d", kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration);
```

If

```
        printf("\n%.4f", kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration);
```

i get 
736204793259769514805539544958332881185808905380376591296729466482703872896792123284994544877461533270472921226586720994654163338779026978512060081697113376452636514975744.0000
736204793259769514805539544958332881185808905380376591296729466482703872896792123284994544877461533270472921226586720994654163338779026978512060081697113376452636514975744.0000

Answer (score 2):

You're using an integer symbol.  Use a float instead.

```
printf("\n%.4f", kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration);
```

Answer (score 1):

why are you printing property id instead of value?
if you want to print your milliseconds do it like this:

```
Float32 currentBufferSize; 
UInt32 size = sizeof(currentBufferSize);
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration, 
                        &size,
                        &currentBufferSize);
printf("\n%.4f", currentBufferSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("\n%.4f", kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration);
```

if you want 4 decimal place precision on a 32-bit floating point number. Drop the .4 if you want arbitrary length.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` means integer, use `%f` for float or double. Read [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).